# Where can one find good documentation describing memory-rank "sparing"?

Tags: memory, redundancy, hardware, data-protection

Where can I find good documentation describing [memory-rank](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_rank) "sparing" (for computer-hardware memory-protection configurations)?  I'm seeking to clarify what benefits it provides and how it's typically implemented.

I'd prefer vendor-neutral documentation.  Have had trouble finding quality docs thus far.

Answer (score 0):

There's an [HP patent on "Rank sparing system and method"](http://www.google.com/patents/US20090031078) that might be your best bet.

I know, links to answers aren't great, but I don't think I'll be able to summarize the patent enough to be useful.